# Nixos where is the path to my generation / system configuration derivation?

Tags: nixos, nix

I'd like to get the root path to the generation / system configuration derivation. Is this path stored somewhere perhaps?

My understanding is that there is a 'derivation' made for your system configuration which in turn has a dependency on other derivations (all the packages etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be this path here `/nix/var/nix/profiles/`: which a symlink for each generation.

And hence I can use:

```
nix-store -q --references /nix/var/nix/profiles/system
```

To list all the derivations my current system config depends on.